# How to create a mock object in Scala?

Tags: scala, unit-testing

I am writing the unit test for a Scala class, code is given below. Here I am trying to mock class B methods, when I am writing test methods for class A. This is what I tried:

**Test class for A class:**

```
class ATest extends FunSuite with BeforeAndAfterAll {
    @InjectMocks
    val a: A = new A

    @Mock
    val b: B = new B

    override def beforeAll(): Unit = {
        super.beforeAll()
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
    }

    test("testSum") {
        Mockito.doReturn(20).when(b).add(12)
        val actualValue = a.sum(12)
        assertResult(20)(actualValue)
    }
 }
```

**Below are Business Classes:**

```
class A{
    val b = new B

    def sum(a:Int):Int={
    val value = b.add(a)
    value
    }
}

class B{
    def add(a:Int):Int={
    a+1
}
}
```

The problem is test method is getting passed only if I keep **var b = new B** instead of **val b = new B** in the A Business class. I think when it is **val b = new B**, mocking is not happening. Please help!

Comment: This would be easier if you injected `b` via the constructor of `A`. The `val b` can probably not be changed anymore by Mockito. Try to change to `class A(b: B) { ... `. That way you can change to whatever `B` you want when you create instances of `A`.

Comment: Thanks for the response Thilo, So if i have many dependent classes, all i need to inject via constructor?